# WPF Routed Command Tunneling

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-commands

I'd like to implement a routed command that tunnels to a user control in my WPF application.

My understanding is that routed commands, like routed events can propagate up and down the visual tree to find the appropriate handler, however I cannot find a simple example of how to do this.

I have no problems creating a routed command that is handled within the same visual tree node in which it is defined.

Please could someone provide a simple explanation or example demonstrating how I wire up a routed command to be handled in a node lower down the visual tree.

Update :
My use case is that I have some functionality that I would like to perform in a tab item, implemented as a user control and I would like to trigger this by keyboard inputs. Therefore I need to handle the keyboard input in my main window then tunnel the command to my specific tab item.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For routed commands, I don't think you can as a result of tight coupling to CanExecute which requires Preview.

In WPF, consider using the [EventManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) for routed events.

There, you can define your routing as Bubbling, Tunneling, or Direct.

**Example:**

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent ButtonColorChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ButtonColorChanged",RoutingStrategy.Bubble,typeof(DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler),typeof(Shirt));

public event RoutedEventHandler ButtonColorChanged  {
    add {AddHandler(ButtonColorChangedEvent,value);}
    remove { RemoveHandler(ButtonColorChangedEvent, value); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your message. I am interested in a tunnelled routed command. Not routed event.

Comment: My mistake. I did find this though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726266/routedcommands-that-use-tunneling-instead-of-bubbling

Answer (score 0):

The routing starts from the root to the focused element tunneling
and then bubbling up to the root from the focus elmt, if no cmd target is specified.

After digging and searching I get the solution for me:
You have to set the "tunneling stop and bubbling start element"
by yourself via "CommandTarget"

```
public partial class Grid_Dienste : UserControl {

    public static Grid_Dienste   current     { get; set; }

    public Grid_Dienste()
    {

        current = this;

        ...

    // this is the prerequsite, works on singeltons
```

in the xaml of the upper node / element you can reference that "current"

```
Command                     = "{Binding cmdLoad}"
CommandTarget               = "{x:Static local:Grid_Dienste.current}"
```

/>So the conclusion: tunneling does not mean from the focus to the bottomst
visual, but from the root to the focus.